# Using Spring Cache with Hazelcast Near Cache

Tags: java, spring, caching, hazelcast

I'm trying to configure Spring CacheManager with Hazelcast. Also, I want to configure Hazelcast's Near Cache so I can retrieve the (already deserialized) instance of my cached object.

Here is my configuration

```
    @Bean
    public HazelcastInstance hazelcastConfig() {
        val config = new Config().setInstanceName("instance");
        val serializationConfig = config.getSerializationConfig();
        addCacheConfig(config, "USERS")
        serializationConfig.addSerializerConfig(new SerializerConfig()
                        .setImplementation(getSerializer())
                        .setTypeClass(User.class)
        return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager(HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance) {
        return new HazelcastCacheManager(hazelcastInstance);
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager chainedTransactionManager(PlatformTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager, HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance) {
        return new ChainedTransactionManager(
                jpaTransactionManager,
                new HazelcastTransactionManager(hazelcastInstance)
        );
    }

    // Configure Near Cache
    private void addCacheConfig(Config config, String cacheName) {
        val nearCacheConfig = new NearCacheConfig()
                .setInMemoryFormat(OBJECT)
                .setCacheLocalEntries(true)
                .setInvalidateOnChange(false)
                .setTimeToLiveSeconds(hazelcastProperties.getTimeToLiveSeconds())
                .setEvictionConfig(new EvictionConfig()
                        .setMaxSizePolicy(ENTRY_COUNT)
                        .setEvictionPolicy(EvictionPolicy.LRU)
                        .setSize(hazelcastProperties.getMaxEntriesSize()));
        config.getMapConfig(cacheName)
                .setInMemoryFormat(BINARY)
                .setNearCacheConfig(nearCacheConfig);
    }
```

Saving and retrieving from the Cache is working fine, but my object is deserialized every time I have a cache hit. I want to avoid this deserialization time using a NearCache, but it doesn´t work. I also tried BINARY memory format.

Is this possible with Hazelcast? Or is this deserialization always executed even if I have a NearCache?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a few changes, it is working now. Here is my conclusion:

So in order to have NearCache working with Spring Cache, all your cached objects should be [Immutable](https://www.journaldev.com/129/how-to-create-immutable-class-in-java). This means final classes and final fields. Also, they all should extend the Serializable interface.